# Flatten super nested JSON to Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have this super nested json file which needs to be in a flat form. Previously I had a similar problem for XML which i solved with the below simple code.

```
df = pdx.read_xml('C:\\python_script\\temp1\\'+file,encoding='utf-8')
df = pdx.fully_flatten(df)
df = df.pipe(flatten)
```

Looking for a similar simple code to do the work.

Here is the data.
https://www.donneesquebec.ca/recherche/dataset/d23b2e02-085d-43e5-9e6e-e1d558ebfdd5/resource/eb4d7620-6aa3-4850-aab6-a0fbe82f2dc1/download/hebdo_20211227_20220102.json

Any help will be appreciated. :)

Comment: what's the shape of the output you want from here?

Comment: I need flat sheet with repeated items. for example for each ocid, there are multiple parties which are contained in json, so i need each party with repeated ocids in separate columns. in short, each json value in a separate column. Let me know if you need further clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After spending almost 2 days, here is the most simplest solution i could have.

```
with open('D:\\Json Data.json') as json_data:
    data = json.load(json_data)
dic_flattened = [flatten(d) for d in data['releases']]     
df = pd.DataFrame(dic_flattened)
```

It goes to the lowest level and make separated columns.
The below article helped me.
https://pypi.org/project/flatten-json/

Answer (score 1):

You can use `json_normalize()` which is pretty effective.
This article explains it very well for different scenarios:
https://towardsdatascience.com/all-pandas-json-normalize-you-should-know-for-flattening-json-13eae1dfb7dd

Here some examples.

```
some_dict = {
    'key1': 'value1',
    'key2': 'value2',
    'key3': 123,
}
df = pd.json_normalize(some_dict)
```

WIth multiple levels, if you don't want all of the levels, you can use:
`pd.json_normalize(data, max_level=1)`

With nested lists you can use `meta` to specify a list of to include:

```
json_object = {
    'key1': 'value1',
    'key2': 'value2',

    'key3': {
        'key3_1': 'value3',
        'key3_2': {
          'key3_2_1': {
              'admission': 'value4',
              'general': 'value5'
          },
          'key3_3': 'value6',
      }
    },
    'key4': [
      { 'key4_1': 'value7' },
      { 'key4_2': 'value8' },
      { 'key4_3': 'value9' }
    ],
}

# you can do:
pd.json_normalize(
    json_object, 
    record_path =['key4'],
    meta=['key1', ['key3', 'key3_2', 'key3_3']],
)
```

If you have lists where not all keys are always present, you can use `errors='ignore'`.

```
pd.json_normalize(
    json_object, 
    record_path =['key4'],
    meta=['key1', ['key3', 'key3_2', 'key3_3']],
    errors='ignore'
)
```

By default, nested values will be separated with `.`, you can change this with `sep=''`:

```
pd.json_normalize(
    json_object, 
    record_path =['key4'],
    meta=['key1', ['key3', 'key3_2', 'key3_3']],
    errors='ignore',
    sep='-'
)
```

It depends on where you get your JSON data, from local file or URL.
For local file:

```
import json
# load data using Python JSON module
with open('data/simple.json','r') as f:
    data = json.loads(f.read())
    
# Flattening JSON data
pd.json_normalize(data)
```

For URLs:

```
import requestsURL = 'http://raw.githubusercontent.com/BindiChen/machine-learning/master/data-analysis/027-pandas-convert-json/data/simple.json'
data = json.loads(requests.get(URL).text)# Flattening JSON data
pd.json_normalize(data)
```